# Should I begin to learn linq or Entity Framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework, ado.net

I have learned basic ADO.NET and I used in one of my app. Now I don't know the next step. Should I learn linq or Entity Framework or both of them? Can someone suggest any learning path ? thanks :)

Comment: LINQ is a base technology in C# - Entity Framework is a **data-access** library that can use Linq - so those are really two totally different things..... learn EF, and you'll learn Linq along the way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) is a set of features that extends powerful query capabilities to the language syntax of C# and Visual Basic. LINQ introduces standard, easily-learned patterns for querying and updating data, and the technology can be extended to support potentially any kind of data store. Visual Studio includes LINQ provider assemblies that enable the use of LINQ with .NET Framework collections, SQL Server databases, ADO.NET Datasets, and XML documents. (msdn)

Among other linq providers you will be interested in

- Linq to objects, for querying in memory data

  > You can use LINQ to query any enumerable collections such as List, Array, or Dictionary. The collection may be user-defined or may be returned by a .NET Framework API (msdn)
- Linq to Entities for querying various RDBMS data sources

  > LINQ to Entities provides Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) support that enables developers to write queries against the Entity Framework conceptual model using Visual Basic or Visual C# (msdn)

Besides all this, I would highly recommend [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) as a playground for getting up to speed with linq.

As far as I am concerned I ditched Sql Server Management Studio or Toad for Oracle in favor of this tool for exploring data in a faster and more meaningful way, but also for experimenting with some complex queries targeting either in memory or remote data stores.

Should you be interested about this particular tool, checkout Jesse Liberty's blog post on this topic as well 
([LINQ From Scratch](http://blog.falafel.com/linq-from-scratch/))

Comment: LINQ From Scratch #2–Deferred Execution
http://blog.falafel.com/linq-from-scratch-2-deferred-execution/
for the second part of Jesse's series on linq

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with both technology in my application and in my opinion you should learn linq first, because if you got good experience about this technology, then you will quicky fast learn EF. On google's all. I used book, whose name's `LINQ to Objects Using C# 4.0`. It has little pages, but has enough knowledge about LINQ and introduces you to this technology. Other good source's here: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b